# How to set Opentelemetry - NodeJS - Auto instrumentation service name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, trace, open-telemetry

I have the following config set in tracing.js (1:1 from the documentation) and I can't figure out how to set the service name. Right now in Datadog all I see is "unknown_service".

```
const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http");
const { diag, DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel } = require('@opentelemetry/api');

//How can I set custom service name?

diag.setLogger(new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.INFO);

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: process.env.OPENTELEMETRY_URL, 
    headers: {},
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});

sdk.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that:
First adding it to your code:

```js
const opentelemetry = require("@opentelemetry/sdk-node");
const { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } = require("@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node");
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require("@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http");
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const { SemanticResourceAttributes } = require('@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions');
const { diag, DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel } = require('@opentelemetry/api');

//How can I set custom service name?

diag.setLogger(new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.INFO);

const sdk = new opentelemetry.NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter({
    url: process.env.OPENTELEMETRY_URL, 
    headers: {},
  }),
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: '<service-name>',
  }),
});

sdk.start();
```

Another way is using the environment variable `OTEL_SERVICE_NAME` as recommended by [@Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj):

```bash
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=<service-name>
```

At last, you can also use the environment variable `OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES`:

```bash
OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=<service-name>
```

Those are the official OpenTelemetry ways of naming a service, IDK if they work with the backend you are using.

That works with OSS tools like Jager and Zipkin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set general-purpose environment variable `OTEL_SERVICE_NAME`.

Doc: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/sdk-configuration/general-sdk-configuration/